# Skype for Business Make a Call on behalf of Delegate

Tags: c#, lync, ucma, ucwa, skype-for-business

We have a simple *one click to call* system who is implemented like this in our web page :

```
<a title="Call" href="tel:1111"></a>
```

Then this is opening a window in the client, and I have to click to finally confirm my call:

[image: S4B confirmation page for calling]

This is working perfectly fine! Except for one thing. If I had delegates in my account, I could not call the number I want on behalf of any of my delegates, and that is a shame.

I succeed to create a system with the Lync Server 2013 by sending a special *"tel:"* string and make **modification to the header** to impersonate my call with the phone number of my delegate. I am making a verification check if the user has the rights to use that phone number of that delegate of course, by sending a simple SQL Request to our database.

The question is: Do you think is a good way to make it work? Alternatively, can I use something far way better and way more secure by using UCMA or UCWA or any other API...